# Magento 2.2.5: Save and Continue Edit Button doesn't work

Tags: magento2, save

I'm doing the Save and Continues button in "Slide" page.

So what I've done til now:
[image]

Everything was perfect, but my `Save and Continue Edit` button doesn't work.
After I click the button, it throws a success message and returns back to the `index page`, but what I want is `detail page`.

I know it because, in `Save.php` file, I've redirected it back to `index page`, but I can't remove that, because when I do that, the save throw an error about missing URI.

And I can't make another `Save.php` just for this `Save and Continue` button, right?

Please give me advice, thanks.

Here is my code:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Slide\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Slide\Edit;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class SaveAndContinueButton
 */
class SaveAndContinueButton extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
            'class' => 'save',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit'],
                ],
            ],
            'sort_order' => 80,
        ];
    }
}
```

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Aht\BannerSlider\Controller\Adminhtml\Slide\Save.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Administrator
 * Date: 20/07/2018
 * Time: 4:15 CH
 */

namespace Aht\BannerSlider\Controller\Adminhtml\Slide;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Aht\BannerSlider\Model\SlideFactory;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $slideFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        SlideFactory $slideFactory
    ) {
        $this->slideFactory = $slideFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
//
        if ($data) {
            try{
                $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

                $model = $this->slideFactory->create()->load($id);
                $data['id'] = $id;
                $model->setData($data);
                $model->save();


                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Update Slide Successfully.'));

                $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');

                return $resultRedirect;
            }
            catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `Save and Continue` button is pressed, a `back/edit` string is appended to the submit url by default, so in your `save` controller you can check for it and set redirect url accordingly.

Change the `return` statement of your save controller to something like below:

```
//check for `back` parameter
if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
}

return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to UI component form XML file

```
<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\ModuleName\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton</item>
</item>
```

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\ModuleName\Edit;

    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

    /**
     * Class SaveAndContinueButton
     */
    class SaveAndContinueButton extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
    {
        /**
         * @return array
         */
        public function getButtonData()
        {
            return [
                'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
                'class' => 'save',
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => [
                        'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit'],
                    ],
                ],
                'sort_order' => 80,
            ];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i thing the problem wasn't there :D because it run into Edit\SaveAndContinueButton successfully, and then it go to Save.php successfully as well, but i redirect it back to index page. :)